# Ideal way to pull ECMWF data

Tags: descartes-labs-platform

I am trying to pull large time series of ECMWF data over single pixels. I'm finding this to be a very slow operation and my guess is that it has to do with the mismatch between how the data is stored natively on platform (WGS) vs. how tiles are defined (UTM), making the raster operation very slow.

I am defining a single-pixel tile as so:

`tile = dl.scenes.DLTile.from_latlon(lat, lon, 30000, 1, 0)`

Even when I try to pull a single day's worth of data (10 bands, 24 scenes in a day) it takes > 1 minute for the raster call to succeed. This won't scale as I need to pull years worth of data over thousands of these single pixel areas.

In an attempt to do everything in WGS, I tried something like:

`aoi = dl.scenes.AOI(geometry=geom, crs='EPSG:4326', resolution=0.25)`

where my `geom` is a GeoJSON Point geometry. However, this didn't work as no bounds are able to be computed for a single point.

Is there a better way to be pulling ECMWF data?

Comment: How big of a region are you pulling these single pixel timeseries in? Since ECMWF is spatially coarse, you can build a stack of data that covers a fairly large area and park it in DL Storage. Then in your workers you can pull the whole thing into memory and hammer it with point queries. But if the points queried are scattered all over the world that won't really work.

Comment: the point queries are scattered across the world in this case